# Temporary files that hang around after script execution

Tags: php, temporary-files

Can I create temporary files with php that expire and get deleted after a predefined time set during file creation, and not when the script finishes execution? My host doesn't allow cron jobs, so php only, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to `cron` you only have one option -- manage file cleanup on your own.

This is, in fact, what the PHP `SESSION` handler does -- it creates a file of session data.  Then, when PHP starts, there is a small chance that it will go through an remove expired files.  (IIRC, there is a 1/100 chance that it will.)

Your best bet is to create a directory to store your temp files in and then use a similar process.

This might give you some ideas: [Session Configuration](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)

Comment: On Linux machines, files stored in `/tmp` are automatically cleaned up after a while - I think the time can be set in a config file somewhere. The OP has not indicated _how long_ the files should remain...

Comment: @Kryten -- On most configs that I've seen, `/tmp` is cleaned out on boot.  Without knowing the contents of the files, or when the OP *wants* them cleared out, I'd not recommend storing them in `/tmp`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$deletetime = time() - $days * 86400; # only do this calculation
$dir = '/path/to/dir';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
   if ((filetype("$dir/$file") == 'file') && (filemtime($file) < $deletetime)) {
    unlink("$dir/$file");
   }
  }
 closedir($handle);
}
```

[reference - webhostingtalk](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1150533)

Also here is a similar question asked before.[Auto delete files after x-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921466/auto-delete-all-files-after-x-time)

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing right now, I was hoping there was a way without a cron job though, which, using this approach, would be the only way to make sure that the files actually get deleted close to their expiration date. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php
$fh = fopen('test.html', 'a');
fwrite($fh, '<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
fclose($fh);

unlink('test.html');
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: Not quite, sorry. I want to create a file in a script that terminates. Without having to call another script, I want that file to get deleted after, lets say, 5 minutes. Thanks anyways!