# php - how delete all files every 5min in x folder?

Tags: php

**i think this code automatically creates a folder name (cache) and i want to delte files in this folder every 5 min, beaucose every time when somone play my video that folder have + a file!!!**

```
//New cache

function gd_cache($link, $source) {
$time = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() + 3600*(+7+date('I')));
$file_name = md5('AA'.$link.'A3Code');
$string = strtotime($time).'@@'.$source;
$file = fopen("cache/".$file_name.".cache",'w');
fwrite($file,$string);
fclose($file);

if(file_exists('cache/'.$file_name.'.cache')) {
    $msn = $source;
} else {
    $msn = $source;
}
return $msn;
}
```

Comment: try http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: Set a cron and get filemtime check if cache is older enough and delete it

Comment: thanks, but im not that good to get that what i want from that website!  Sanjit Bhardwaj

Comment: use a php timer

Comment: That `if-else` though, what's the use of that?

Comment: when my visitors play my video, in cache folder is + 1 more file, so i have 1000 visitors for day , in that folder i have more 1000 file!,  kerbholz

Answer (score 2):

In the if condition use unlink function on success

```
if(file_exists('cache/'.$file_name.'.cache')) {
   $msn = $source;
   unlink('cache/'.$file_name.'.cache');
} else {
   $msn = $source;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i change that and i put your code that is not wokring anymore!

Comment: the if condition you are using is for checking if cache is available or not?

Comment: now yes is  available, but i can delete that is not probelm

Comment: your main video file is in your cache or in other folder?

Comment: in cache folder is video playback file, the file is like this (hsgdghegyfgfhbskgkjdfe) but if i open that on insade of the file is the playback link of my videos

Comment: pleas check this post maybe this code help me but i don't know how to use this to delete files in my cache folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921466/auto-delete-all-files-after-x-time